# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, windows, wamp, php-5.6

I am using WampServer  3.1.0 and PHP version 5.6.31 in windows, i am getting an error like,

php_error :

> [06-Dec-2018 10:13:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:19 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext\php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [06-Dec-2018 10:13:21 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext\php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [06-Dec-2018 10:13:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:32 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0 [06-Dec-2018 10:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext\php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [06-Dec-2018 10:13:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext\php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.
>
> in Unknown on line 0
>
> [06-Dec-2018 10:13:36 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
>   dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll'
>   - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0

**PHP Version : 5.6.31**

[image]

Php.ini :

https://justpaste.it/57qi2

How can i solve the above error?

Comment: do the mentioned files exist in `'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.6.31/ext/`?

Comment: @PhilippSander Yes, screenshot:  https://snag.gy/wG3jPc.jpg

Comment: maybe it's a permission issue

Comment: @PhilippSander How to solve this error?

Comment: Solved. After start all wamp services in Windows Services

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was very similar. The problem .dll existed but it had a dependency on another dll. I ran a dependency checker and found that it was dependent on the dll fbclient.dll which was not on my system. I found the dll, put in in a directory on the system path and the problem went away. Verify that you actually need the dll. If it's not needed, comment it out in the php file. That will also solve the problem.